# How to find range of values for the first-stage decisions resulting in the same cuts in two-stage stochastic programming?

Tags: stochastic-programming

Suppose we have a two-stage stochastic program as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min \ & c^Tx + \mathbb{E}_\xi[Q(x,\xi)] \\
&  \text{where}\\
 &Q(x,\xi)=\min q(\xi)^Ty\\
&Tx+W(\xi)y=h(\xi)\\
&y \ge 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I am wondering how it is possible to find a set of values for the first-stage decisions such that in the L-Shape method, the same (optimality) cuts are generated. For example, suppose we have a problem like the follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \min \ & 5x_1+10x_2 + \mathbb{E}_\xi[q_1y_1+q_2y_2] \\
& y_1 + 2y_2 \ge d_1 -x_1 \\
& y_1 \ge d_2 -2x_2\\
& 0 \le x_1 \le 10 \\
& 0 \le x_2\le 10 \\
& y_1,y_2 \ge 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $(q_1,q_2,d_1,d_2)$ takes two values $(20,10,5,10)$ and $(15,25,12,5)$ with equal probabilities.